# Which is the current setup to use OCaml in Vim?

Tags: vim, ocaml

I never used Vi or Vim, but it seems that it is the best option to edit OCaml files.
Unfortunately I am lost with so many things to care about: ocaml-vi-addon, vi-scripts, otags etc.

I broke my initial fear of Vim using [cream](http://cream.sourceforge.net/home.html),
but I am in doubt if I need any package* other than vim-scripts.

- -> I use Debian, maybe this info is useless

Comment: Emacs is another best option to edit OCaml files, unless you also have fear of Emacs.

Comment: Yes, I have; and it is bigger than vim's. I swear I tried, but emacs definitely isn't for me.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The default mode for OCaml is all there is to it really. You could consider using the following plugins:

https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic - syntax checking

https://github.com/def-lkb/merlin - auto completion

https://github.com/jpalardy/vim-slime - repl integration

https://github.com/OCamlPro/ocp-indent - code formatting

Comment: You could also add [ocp-indent](https://github.com/OCamlPro/ocp-indent) to your answer.

Comment: Good suggestion, I actually do use ocp-indent.

Comment: Are they compatible with each other? Don't are they included in the package vim-scripts? Will vim-scripts be needed at all?

Comment: All of the the above are completely compatible. The easiest way to get going quickly with these is using Vundle.

Comment: @rgrinberg How do you switch between .mli and .ml files? I look for `a.vim` analog for OCaml.

Comment: @Stas there's actually support for that in the default vim plugin for OCaml. I can't tell you the original key since I've rebound it but the function is `OCaml_switch`

Comment: @Stas merlin provides `:ML Module_name` and `:MLI Module_name` for navigation within a project as well.

Answer (score 16):

Put these lines in your ~/.vimrc file:

```
filetype indent on
filetype plugin on
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.ml,*.mli compiler ocaml
syntax on
```

Then you get some nice shortcuts:

- `\s` switches between the .ml and .mli file
- `\c` comments the current line / selection (`\C` to uncomment)
- `%` jumps to matching let/in, if/then, etc (see `:h matchit-install`)
- `\t` tells you the type of the thing under the cursor (if you compiled with `-annot`)

Also, Vim can then parse the output of the compiler and jump to the correct location.

Comment: To check if your version of vim supports the ocaml compiler type :compiler in your vim console. You will get a list of available compilers.

Answer (score 7):

The answers are quite old, I figured this thread requires an update as the introduction of [LSP](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/) as a de-facto standard have recently revolutionized the old text editors (vim, emacs...etc).

### LSP (IDE-like features like autocompletions, refactoring etc)

The current state-of-the-art is to use the official OCaml Language Server:
https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml-lsp

You can use coc.nvim for Vim8+ and Neovim and configure it to use ocaml-lsp:
https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/wiki/Language-servers#ocaml-and-reasonml

Or, instead of coc.nvim, you can use the latest Neovim nightly (0.5+) as a client for the OCaml Language Server: https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig#ocamllsp

### Improved syntax highlighting

Use vim-ocaml to improve syntax highlighting:
https://github.com/ocaml/vim-ocaml

Alternatively vim-ocaml is embedded in vim-polyglot, so you don't need to install vim-ocaml separately:
https://github.com/sheerun/vim-polyglot

### Bonus

This is a nice video explaining where the community is heading for the following years regarding tooling and the OCaml platform in general:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E8T_4zqWmq8&t

### Bonus 2: vimrc and init.vim

My init.vim, compatible as a .vimrc too:
https://github.com/nicobao/setup/blob/master/vim/init.vim

Great vimmer's .vimrc/init.vim:
https://github.com/awesome-streamers/awesome-streamerrc

Answer (score 3):

One wants support from his editor for these reasons:

1. better presentation via syntax highlighting/folding
2. better automatic indentation
3. spot errors earlier via background compilation, syntax highlighting (again) or by any other mean
4. inline debugging
5. introspection to list available names/methods, see an object type, and so on.

For 1 and 2, the default should be good enough, although there is [this ocp-indent plugin](https://github.com/OCamlPro/ocp-indent) that try to do a better job.

For 3 I resort on syntax highlighting, and do not know anything better for vim.

With regard to inline debugging, I never managed to make use of ocamldebug from the command line so never tried from the editor.

Regarding introspection, I can't recommend enough [the annot program](https://github.com/avsm/ocaml-annot), that can be installed as a vim plugin as explained in the README.

Once installed you can get the type of anything under the cursor with only two keystrokes, which is very convenient for a language capable of inferring the most complex types.

Comment: annot functionality is actually built in to newer versions of vim's ocaml mode. It's bound to `<leader>t`

Comment: @rgrinberg That is what I am talking about when I say "I am lost" :)

Comment: How about 5? I was wondering if there is some plugin for vim to list the modules/names in the current file.

Answer (score 1):

There is a really nice guide at https://github.com/ocaml/merlin/wiki/vim-from-scratch

Since Stack Overflow does not appreciate link only answers, here are the commands, but really - visit that page for insights and context.

```
opam install merlin
```

Add this to .vimrc:

```
let g:opamshare = substitute(system('opam config var share'),'\n$','','''')
execute "set rtp+=" . g:opamshare . "/merlin/vim"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative worth mentioning is [Onivim](https://www.onivim.io/) a Vim-based editor which comes with [out-of-the-box support for OCaml and ReasonML via `ocaml-lsp`](https://onivim.github.io/docs/languages/reason-ocaml).

Its front-end is actually written with OCaml (well, ReasonML) and it uses a fork of Vim ([libvim](https://github.com/onivim/libvim)) on the back-end. It's still in alpha and doesn't offer the full Vim experience yet, however, but I've already used it full-time for about a year myself.

It's also a commercial product, but free for non-commercial use and [time-delayed open source](https://onivim.github.io/docs/other/faq#is-onivim-2-open-source).

*(Full disclaimer: I used to work on Onivim, but at time of writing I do not)*

Answer (score 0):

Omlet used to be a good mode for Vim: [Author's page](http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~dbaelde/productions/omlet.html), [vim.org](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1196). Event if there has been no new version since 2005, it might suit your needs. If you try it, tell us what you think!